# При ошибках PHP выводит исходный код

Tags: apache, php, ubuntu

Всем вечер добрый.
Настроил ispconfig на Ubuntu, при ошибках в php файлах выводиться исходный код скрипта, например

```
<?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SERVER)
```

Вместо ошибки выводит

```
?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SERVER)
```

Уже перерыл весь php.ini но толку нет, может кто сталкивался как можно исправить?

```
Проблема решилась, ошибка оказалась в FTP, при загрузке файлов,  обрезался знак первый знак <b><</b>, сейчас буду смотреть почему так
```

Comment: > Проблема решилась, ошибка оказалась в
> FTP, при загрузке файлов,  обрезался
> знак первый знак <b><</b>, сейчас буду
> смотреть почему так

а в каком режиме общается фтп?

Answer (score 1):

`ispconfig` настроили чтобы `php` работал? Может все-таки лучше `php` переустановить?

Comment: ispconfig работает хорошо, php свежий стоит думаю смысла перестанавливать не вижу